# Java check if file is empty: IOException: null

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to load a file to my ArrayList, program creates a file if it doesn't exist. I'm getting IOException: Null as at the beginning file is empty. How I can avoid that error and check if file is empty or not? Here's my code:

```
     File f = new File(fileName);

     try {
        if( !f.exists() ){
            f.createNewFile();
        }

        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        scores = (ArrayList<Score>) inputStream.readObject();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
     } finally {
         ...
     }
```

Comment: what is your fileName

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`File.length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) to obtain the size number of bytes of the file:

> The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist. Some operating systems may return 0L for pathnames denoting system-dependent entities such as devices or pipes.

Comment: Tnx, that is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your program needs a minor bit of restructuring, then it won't try and load the empty file

```
File f = new File(fileName);

     try {
        if( f.length() == 0 ){
            f.createNewFile();
        } else {
            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            scores = (ArrayList<Score>) inputStream.readObject();
        }
     } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
     } finally {
         ...
```